# TypeError: show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, matplotlib

The simple code below is giving the error in the title. The compiler is complaining that 2 positional arguments were given to plt.show(), but only one was expected. However as you can see from the code only one argument "fig1" was given?

```
def test_plot_episode_stats(stats):
    fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.plot(stats.episode_lengths)
    plt.show(fig1)
    return fig1

EpisodeStats = namedtuple("Stats", ["episode_lengths", "episode_rewards"])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    stats = EpisodeStats(
        episode_lengths=np.random.randint(10, size=10),
        episode_rewards=np.random.randint(10, size=10))
    test_plot_episode_stats(stats)
```

Comment: `plt.show(fig1)` passes two arguments: `self` (which is actually `plt`), and `fig1`. Are you sure you didn't mean to do `fig1.show()` with no arguments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800873/show-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

Answer (score 0):

The function `plt.show()` means to show all open figure windows.
So, it does not necessarily need to accept any `fig` object as positional argument.
Actually, it only supports the keyword argument `block=Ture|False`, according to the document.

In addition, the function signature `plt.show(*args, **kwargs)` does not mean it accept `fig` object as positional argument.
The true signature depends on the backend currently in use, as the code inside `plt.show()`:

```py
def show(*args, **kwargs):
    '''...'''
    return _backend_mod.show(*args, **kwargs)
```