# show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got some good feedback on the code I have been working on and I have gotten everything to run on google collab but when i run the exact same code on Visual studio the error i get is this:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

            
def run_analytics(data):
  for i in set(data['MovementNumber'].values):
    print("Plot for Movement Number " + str(i))
    data2 = data.loc[data['MovementNumber'] == i]
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    xdata = data2['PlayerPosX'].values
    ydata = data2['PlayerPosY'].values
    zdata = data2['PlayerPosZ'].values
    len(xdata)
    plot1 = ax.scatter3D(xdata[:,1], ydata, zdata, c=zdata)
    plt.show(plot1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  data = pd.read_csv('Assetslog_912021_11.csv')
  data.columns = ['Time', 'Fixed Delta', 'Movement Time', 'MovementNumber', 'MovementDir', 'Rest Flag', 'DistortionDigit', 'RobotForceX','RobotForceY','RobotForceZ', 'PrevPositionX','PrevPositionY','PrevPositionZ', 'TargetPosX', 'TargetPosY', 'TargetPosZ', 'PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosY', 'PlayerPosZ', 'RobotVelX','RobotVelY','RobotVelZ', 'LocalPosX', 'LocalPosY', 'LocalPosZ', 'PerpError' ]  
  data['RobotForce'] = data[['RobotForceX', 'RobotForceY', 'RobotForceZ']].values.tolist()
  data['StartPos'] = data[['PrevPositionX', 'PrevPositionY', 'PrevPositionZ']].values.tolist()
  data['TargetPos'] = data[['TargetPosX', 'TargetPosY', 'TargetPosZ']].values.tolist()
  data['PlayerPos'] = data[['PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosY', 'PlayerPosZ']].values.tolist()
  data['RobotVel'] = data[['RobotVelX', 'RobotVelY', 'RobotVelZ']].values.tolist()
  run_analytics(data)
```

I know it could be optimized more but for now i am not too worried about that part. I do know i need to add this:

```
class MyClass():
      
  def __init__(self,show):
    self.plot1 = plot1 
    self.data = data
    self.run_analytics = run_analytics
```

but i dont think I am calling self correctly. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

Don't need this equalize

```
plot1 = ax.scatter3D(xdata[:,1], ydata, zdata, c=zdata)
```

you must change like this:

```
ax.scatter3D(xdata[:,1], ydata, zdata, c=zdata)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`show()` function doesn't take arguments:

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

            
def run_analytics(data):
  for i in set(data['MovementNumber'].values):
    print("Plot for Movement Number " + str(i))
    data2 = data.loc[data['MovementNumber'] == i]
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    xdata = data2['PlayerPosX'].values
    ydata = data2['PlayerPosY'].values
    zdata = data2['PlayerPosZ'].values
    len(xdata)
    plot1 = ax.scatter3D(xdata[:,1], ydata, zdata, c=zdata)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  data = pd.read_csv('Assetslog_912021_11.csv')
  data.columns = ['Time', 'Fixed Delta', 'Movement Time', 'MovementNumber', 'MovementDir', 'Rest Flag', 'DistortionDigit', 'RobotForceX','RobotForceY','RobotForceZ', 'PrevPositionX','PrevPositionY','PrevPositionZ', 'TargetPosX', 'TargetPosY', 'TargetPosZ', 'PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosY', 'PlayerPosZ', 'RobotVelX','RobotVelY','RobotVelZ', 'LocalPosX', 'LocalPosY', 'LocalPosZ', 'PerpError' ]  
  data['RobotForce'] = data[['RobotForceX', 'RobotForceY', 'RobotForceZ']].values.tolist()
  data['StartPos'] = data[['PrevPositionX', 'PrevPositionY', 'PrevPositionZ']].values.tolist()
  data['TargetPos'] = data[['TargetPosX', 'TargetPosY', 'TargetPosZ']].values.tolist()
  data['PlayerPos'] = data[['PlayerPosX', 'PlayerPosY', 'PlayerPosZ']].values.tolist()
  data['RobotVel'] = data[['RobotVelX', 'RobotVelY', 'RobotVelZ']].values.tolist()
  run_analytics(data)
```